# pyspark split stringtype from integertypes for explorative analysis

Tags: string, types, split, pyspark

I would like to split the stringtypes of my df from integers in PySpark and execute some descriptive analyses for the integertypes. I wrote this function, is there a more efficient way?

```
for item in df.columns:
    if df.dtypes[item][1] =='string':
        print("this column is a string ")
    else:
        df.agg(F.min(df[item])).show()                                  
        max= df.agg(F.max(df[item]))                                  
        max.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

To analyze a dataframe's structure you could use:

```
df.describe()
df.schema()
df.toPandas().info()
df.cube("col1"[, "col2"]).count().show()
```

And last but not least [DataFrameStatFunctions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=stat#pyspark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions)